# Getting parameter for method when passed through JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling method as follows:

```
public JsonResult RenderTo_Observation(string AccountID)
{
    try
    {

        return Json(new
        {
            redirectUrl = Url.Action("Observation", "PP",  AccountID),
            isRedirect = true
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I am calling Observation method in PP Controller which is defined as below:

```
public ActionResult Observation(string AccountID)
{
    ViewBag.AccountID = AccountID;
    return View();
}
```

I am passing accountid parameter it it as we can see it in:

```
redirectUrl = Url.Action("Observation", "PP",  AccountID)
```

In this i have made sure that AccountID has its desired value.

But when the function Observation is getting called through it,

Its not showing me AccountID parameter value as it was while passing.

Each time it shows me null when function gets called.

What is mistake in above code???

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your action arguments as an object:

```
redirectUrl = Url.Action("Observation", "PP", new { AccountID })
```

This allows the UrlHelper to create a parameter with the correct name.